# Calling a python method from C/C++, and extracting its return value

Tags: c++, python, c, python-c-api, python-embedding

I'd like to call a custom function that is defined in a Python module from C. I have some preliminary code to do that, but it just prints the output to stdout.

**mytest.py**

```py
import math

def myabs(x):
    return math.fabs(x)
```

**test.cpp**

```c
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('.')");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import mytest;");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print mytest.myabs(2.0)");
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I extract the return value into a C `double` and use it in C?

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.python.org/c-api/?  It seems to answer your question.  http://docs.python.org/c-api/number.html#PyNumber_Float seems to be what you're looking for.  What's wrong with it?  What more do you need?

Comment: The question really is how to access the returned object from `mytest.myabs(2.0)`. Once I have a pointer to it, I can easily convert it to a float using the PyNumber_Float function.

Comment: Can we just see a answer with a code example and be done with it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As explained before, using PyRun_SimpleString seems to be a bad idea.

You should definitely use the methods provided by the C-API (http://docs.python.org/c-api/).

Reading the introduction is the first thing to do to understand the way it works.

First, you have to learn about PyObject that is the basic object for the C API. It can represent any kind of python basic types (string, float, int,...).

Many functions exist to convert for example python string to char* or PyFloat to double.

First, import your module :

```
PyObject* myModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"mytest");
PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
```

Then getting a reference to your function :

```
PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char*)"myabs");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyFloat_FromDouble(2.0));
```

Then getting your result :

```
PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args)
```

And getting back to a double :

```
double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
```

You should obviously check the errors (cf. link given by Mark Tolonen).

If you have any question, don't hesitate. Good luck.

Comment: I will accept your answer because of the useful tips, but it would have been more helpful to me if you could provide a complete working C module calling the above python function.

Comment: If you're calling an object's class method, do you need to pass that object in the args?

Comment: Although it is accepted, this answer is unfortunately not a good template for calling Python code (and I've seen it referenced elsewhere). The `PyTuple_Pack` line leaks a `float` object each time it is executed. The function can be called without manual conversion and tuple creation, with `result = PyObject_CallFunction(myFunction, "d", 2.0)`. The import can be written as `module = PyImport_ImportModule("mytest")` (without creating a Python string).

Comment: I just had some troubles with this code, I didn't succeed to import my code, so all there is to do is add `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('.')");` and then use the `PyObject` method. thanks for this code, it work now.

Comment: Does this work for calling a function that is defined within a class?

Comment: If you're using Python >3.5, `PyString_FromString()` is `PyUnicode_FromString()`.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a sample code I wrote (with the help of various online sources) to send a string to a Python code, then return a value.

Here is the C code `call_function.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   // Set PYTHONPATH TO working directory
   setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);

   PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue, *presult;


   // Initialize the Python Interpreter
   Py_Initialize();


   // Build the name object
   pName = PyString_FromString((char*)"arbName");

   // Load the module object
   pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);


   // pDict is a borrowed reference 
   pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);


   // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
   pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, (char*)"someFunction");

   if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
   {
       pValue=Py_BuildValue("(z)",(char*)"something");
       PyErr_Print();
       printf("Let's give this a shot!\n");
       presult=PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,pValue);
       PyErr_Print();
   } else 
   {
       PyErr_Print();
   }
   printf("Result is %d\n",PyInt_AsLong(presult));
   Py_DECREF(pValue);

   // Clean up
   Py_DECREF(pModule);
   Py_DECREF(pName);

   // Finish the Python Interpreter
   Py_Finalize();


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Python code, in file `arbName.py`:

```
 def someFunction(text):
    print 'You passed this Python program '+text+' from C! Congratulations!'
    return 12345
```

I use the command `gcc call_function.c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lpython2.6 ; ./a.out` to run this process. I'm on redhat. I recommend using PyErr_Print(); for error checking.

Comment: Calling `a.out` would be better as `./a.out` because your call to `a.out` relies on working directory being in PATH, which is not a very common configuration. You should also consider providing `-o` option to GCC to give the executable a better name.

Comment: See [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/238706) on Meta SE. If you can get to the revision history but could not see the changes in markup, just switch the diff view to `side-by-side markdown`. There are buttons at the top of each revision in revision history that switch diff view. If you do not understand what the markup does, refer to [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If you’re editing a post, the editor has built-in help – see the orange question mark to the top right of the editor.

Comment: this gives me a segfault on python 2.7 :(

Comment: Compilation line (for c++) :
g++ call_function.cpp `python2.7-config --cflags` `python2.7-config --ldflags` -o call_function

Comment: In python3 replace `PyString_FromString` to `PyUnicode_FromString` and `Py_Finalize` to `Py_FinalizeEx`.

Comment: the reason for why a "z" was used in `pValue=Py_BuildValue("(z)",(char*)"something");` is it represents a Python str/null object and a C++ char*. For other arg types look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/arg.html

Answer (score 11):

A complete example of calling a Python function and retrieving the result is located at http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
            for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                pValue = PyInt_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
                if (!pValue) {
                    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                /* pValue reference stolen here: */
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see my followup question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441365/calling-python-hello-world-function-from-c-parsing-string-arguments

Answer (score 6):

To prevent the extra .py file as in the other answers, you can just retrieve the `__main__` module, which is created by the first call to `PyRun_SimpleString`:

```
PyObject *moduleMainString = PyString_FromString("__main__");
PyObject *moduleMain = PyImport_Import(moduleMainString);

PyRun_SimpleString(
    "def mul(a, b):                                 \n"\
    "   return a * b                                \n"\
);

PyObject *func = PyObject_GetAttrString(moduleMain, "mul");
PyObject *args = PyTuple_Pack(2, PyFloat_FromDouble(3.0), PyFloat_FromDouble(4.0));

PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);

printf("mul(3,4): %.2f\n", PyFloat_AsDouble(result)); // 12
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, this is answered at the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html). However, since I come from Python and don't have that much experience using C/C++, I had some issues running it with Python 3. So here is my full working example to get the Python docs running after spending some time on other posts of stackoverflow:

File `c_function.c`

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();

    // I had to add the following two lines to make it work
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
            for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                pValue = PyLong_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
                if (!pValue) {
                    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                /* pValue reference stolen here: */
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        return 120;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

File `multiply.py`

```
def multiply(a,b):
    print("Will compute", a, "times", b)
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        c = c + b
    return c
```

We need to compile and link it. This can be done with the command:

```
gcc c_function.c -c $(python3.6-config --cflags) -fPIC
```

followed by

```
gcc c_function.o $(python3.6-config --ldflags) -o call
```

for the example of Python 3.6. Afterwards, the example from the Python docs can just be executed by

```
./call multiply multiply 3 2
```

Comment: This is huge!!!  Thank you! ``// I had to add the following two lines to make it work
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");``

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the python method somehow and run it with `PyObject_CallObject()`. To do that, you can provide Python a way to set the function, as the [Extending and Embedding Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c) example does.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the return value to a variable, then you can use something like PyEval_GetGlobals() and PyDict_GetItemString() to get the PyObject. From there, PyNumber_Float can get you the value you want.

I suggest browsing through the whole API - certain things become obvious when you see the different methods that are available to you, and there may well be a better method than the one I've described.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using BOOST to embedded Python to C++ [This working C module should help]

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void main()
{
using namespace boost::python;
 Py_Initialize();
 PyObject* filename = PyString_FromString((char*)"memory_leak_test");
     PyObject* imp = PyImport_Import(filename);
     PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(imp,(char*)"begin");
     PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyString_FromString("CacheSetup"));
     PyObject* retured_value = PyObject_CallObject(func, args); // if you have arg
     double retured_value = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
 std::cout << result << std::endl;
 Py_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Where is the boost part in this script ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal executable version that also works with Python 3 (tested with Python 2.7 and 3.9).

Links into the docs are included in the comments, but all are accessible under https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // see https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html
    // NULL objects are special and Py_CLEAR knows this
    PyObject *module = NULL, *result = NULL;

    // https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html
    module = PyImport_ImportModule("mytest");
    if (!module) {
        // Python generally uses exceptions to indicate an error state which
        // gets flagged in the C-API (a NULL pointer in this case) indicating
        // "something" failed. the PyErr_* API should be used to get more
        // details
        goto done;
    }

    // see https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod
    // and https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#building-values
    result = PyObject_CallMethod(module, "myabs", "f", 3.14);
    if (!result) {
        goto done;
    }

    // make sure we got our number back
    if (PyFloat_Check(result)) {
        printf("Successfully got a float: %f\n", PyFloat_AsDouble(result));
    } else {
        printf("Successfully got something unexpected!\n");
    }

  done:
    // see https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html
    PyErr_Print();

    // see https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html
    Py_CLEAR(result);
    Py_CLEAR(module);

    // Optionally release Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This uses the OP's Python code `mytest.py`, or this one-line equivalent:

```py
from math import fabs as myabs
```

Building is going to be OS/Python version specific, but the following works for me:

```sh
cc -o test -I/usr/include/python3.9 /usr/lib/libpython3.9.so test.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and direct answer to your question:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Python.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    const char *scriptDirectoryName = "/yourDir";
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("mytest");

    PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,(char*)"myabs");
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyFloat_FromDouble(-2.0));


    PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);
    double getResult = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I receive the following error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not declared in this scope
     PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);