# PyImport_Import cannot find module

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to call a python function inside my c++

When i import my python module it gives this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'`

Here is how i'm importing the module:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_FromString("test");
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if (pModule == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::exit(1);
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I feel like this must have to do with my project structure. It currently looks like this:

```
project
|-- main.cpp
|-- test.py
```

I'm not sure if it's worth mentioning, but the executable is in the same directory, and it's being run from that directory aswell.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you check if "." is on the search path for modules? You can dump the contents of `sys.path` in a PyEval statement to find out.

Comment: you can do import with one line `PyImport_ImportModule("test")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Py_SetPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPath) before `Py_Initialize()` to set the `sys.path`.

Here is a longer list of what can be done before you initialize the interpreter: [pre-init-safe](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#pre-init-safe)

Isolate the embedded Python interpreter and set the path properly to avoid problems with partially using the modules of the installed Python version.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by setting the "PYTHONPATH" environment variable:

```
setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
```

Thanks @Botje

Answer (score 0):

As dwib mentioned I was able to overcome by the error by setting the PYTHONPATH variable in my zshrc (may be bashrc for you) file.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PATH:/home/jk/jk/c
```

where /home/jk/jk/c is the folder where my file was residing.

Also sourced it

```
. ~/.zshrc
```