# Python C_API with GCC - Python.h not found

Tags: python, c, gcc, python-c-api

I am testing the Python C_API using the program shown below with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 18.04.  I have tried compiling with Clang-10 and GCC 7.5, but in both cases the compiler is unable to locate Python.h.

When I run this string:

```
sudo gcc -v -shared -fPIC -l /usr/include/python3.8 -I/usr/lib -I/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/lib/python3.8 -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Wall -o Python_Math.o Python_Math.c
```

I get "Python_Math.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory  #include <Python.h>"

I changed the string to this:

```
sudo gcc Python_Math.c -o Python_Math.o -v -shared -fPIC -l/usr/lib -l/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/python3.8 -l/usr/lib/python3.8 -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -Wall
```

and I get:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/python3.8

So I reduced the string to this:

```
sudo gcc Python_Math.c -o Python_Math.o -v -shared -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -Wall
```

Now the program compiles and links but when I run "nm" on Python_Math.o it shows all the imported symbols (including Py_Initialize) as undefined.

Finally I reduced the string to this:

```
sudo gcc Python_Math.c -o Python_Math.o -v -shared -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lpython3.8 -Wall
```

and again it compiles and links but nm still shows symbols as "undefined."

If I change "I" in the string above to "L" for -L/usr/include/python3.8 I again get "Python.h" not found, and a message re the search paths for includes, which shows usr/include in the path.

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The problem appears to be the path to Python.h.  Locate says Python.h is located in /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h.

A question at [Embedding Python in C, linking fails with undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672572/embedding-python-in-c-linking-fails-with-undefined-reference-to-py-initialize) said to add  "embed" on Ubuntu 20.04, but I haven't found a way to make that work with Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the complete program:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int Lib_Math(char* module_name, char* fn_name, double value_in)
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i = 0;

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(module_name);

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, fn_name);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(value_in);
            pValue = PyLong_FromDouble(value_in);

            if (!pValue) {
                Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                return 1;
            }

            /* pValue reference stolen here: */
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);

            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", fn_name);
        }    
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", module_name);
        return 1;
    }
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        return 120;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help with getting the right link options.

Comment: The symbols will be provided by libpython.so, use ldd to see the dependency,  or you could enforce the linking against the static version, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48796014/5769463

Comment: Locate libpython.so finds nothing, but libpython3.8.so is found, so I'll work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the `I` and `L`/`l` options. The right syntax is:

```
gcc -v -shared -fPIC \
    -I/usr/include/python3.8 \
    -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python3.8 \
    -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm \
    -Wall -o Python_Math.so Python_Math.c
```

`-I` for include dirs, `-L` for libraries dirs and `-l` for library files.

The compiler and linker options can be obtained by running the commands:

```
python3.8-config --includes
  -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/usr/include/python3.8

python3.8-config --ldflags
  -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib  -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -lm
```

You compiles the module as shared library object `*.so`, so objects like `Py_Initialize` will be available at run time.

Comment: Your string compiles, but all the symbols from Python.h still show as "Undefined" when I do nm Python_Math.o in Ubuntu.

Comment: In the verbose version /usr/include/python3.8 shows as the first entry in the "include path" section, so GCC searches that folder, but I'm mystified why the symbols show as "Undefined."

Comment: I ran "nm" on libpython3.8 and the missing symbols are there.  Now just to link against it.