# How can convert PyObject variable to Mat in c++ opencv code

Tags: opencv, mat, python-c-api, python-embedding, pyobject

I have a c++ facerecognition code and a python code in opencv. In python code i read frames from a robot and  i want to send this fram to my c++ code.
I use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value) tho call python function in c++ function.

my c++ function is embed.cpp:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include </home/nao/Desktop/python/boost_1_61_0/boost/python/extract.hpp>
#include </home/nao/Desktop/python/boost_1_61_0/boost/python/converter/registry.hpp>

namespace py = boost::python;
int main()
{

// Set PYTHONPATH TO working directory
   setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue, *presult;
// Initialize the Python Interpreter
Py_Initialize();
// Build the name object
pName = PyString_FromString((char*)"alvideo2");
// Load the module object
 pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
// pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, (char*)"showNaoImage");

if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
{
 pValue=Py_BuildValue("(z)",(char*)"something");
PyErr_Print();
printf("Let's give this a shot!\n");
presult=PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,pValue);
PyErr_Print();
} else{
PyErr_Print();
}

cv::imshow("Original_image",presult);

cvWaitKey(0);

Py_DECREF(pValue);
// Clean up
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);
// Finish the Python Interpreter
 Py_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

and my python code is alvideo2.py:

```
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-
# Get an image from NAO. Display it and save it using PIL.

import cv2
import os #new
import sys
import time 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from naoqi import ALProxy
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def showNaoImage(text):
  """
  First get an image from Nao, then show it on the screen with PIL.
  """
  IP = "192.168.1.18"  # Replace here with your NaoQi's IP address.
  PORT = 9559

  # Read IP address from first argument if any.
  #if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #IP = sys.argv[1]

  camProxy = ALProxy("ALVideoDevice", IP, PORT)
  resolution = 2    # VGA
  colorSpace = 11   # RGB

  videoClient = camProxy.subscribe("python_client", resolution, colorSpace, 5)

  #t0 = time.time()

  # Get a camera image.
  # image[6] contains the image data passed as an array of ASCII chars.
  naoImage = camProxy.getImageRemote(videoClient)

  # Time the image transfer.
  #print "acquisition delay ", t1 - t0

  camProxy.unsubscribe(videoClient)


  # Now we work with the image returned and save it as a PNG  using ImageDraw
  # package.

  # Get the image size and pixel array.
  imageWidth = naoImage[0]
  imageHeight = naoImage[1]
  array = naoImage[6]

  # Create a PIL Image from our pixel array.
  im = Image.frombytes("RGB", (imageWidth, imageHeight), array)
  frame=np.array(im)
  #cv2.imshow("Faces found", frame)
  #cv2.waitKey(0) 
  return frame
```

So, my question is how can i use returnd fram in `cv::imshow("Original_image",presult);` ? . in otherwise how can i convert pyobject to Mat?

thanks alot.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if the posted answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

For **Python 3.x C-API**:

In Python side return the `frame` in `bytearray` format:

```
return bytearray(frame)
```

and in cpp side get it by `PyByteArray_AsString` function:

```
pData = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
uchar *data = (uchar *)PyByteArray_AsString(pData );
cv::Mat img(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `showNaoImage` returns a numpy array, you can use numpy's C API to extract values from the frame, or obtain the pointer to the memory that holds the values. See [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.html), specifically the part that deals with [array data access](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#array-structure-and-data-access).

To convert the data to a `Mat` array accepted by `cv::imshow`, use the `Mat` constructor with the data and its dimensions. For example:

```cpp
// numpy array created from a PIL image is 3-dimensional:
// height x width x num_channels (num_channels being 3 for RGB)
assert (PyArray_NDIM(presult) == 3 && PyArray_SHAPE(presult)[2] == 3);

// Extract the metainformation and the data.
int rows = PyArray_SHAPE(presult)[0];
int cols = PyArray_SHAPE(presult)[1];
void *frame_data = PyArray_DATA(presult);

// Construct the Mat object and use it.
Mat cv_frame(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, frame_data);
cv::imshow("Original_image", cv_frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there should be a specific function available in opencv for python called *pyopencv_to(pyobject, cv::mat, ... )*, which also takes strides into the account and can handle both gray and color images.