# Convert Python script to C++

Tags: python, c++, converters, caffe

I have a set of scripts that use some dependencies, such as caffe(used for deep learning). The script detects an object and draws a rectangle alongside it(it's used in a car simulator) My question is this, what is the best method to use the script in C++? I can manually convert all the code to C++ and just use it as a separate module or I can make a separate module that loads the script using a C++ wrapper on the python API and just call the python command in the wrapper and let the funny business run somewhere else(pretty much embed the python in C++). What's the most efficient method regarding time input-reward outcome?

Comment: Why not just use Cython in the meantime?

Comment: Fully depends on the circumstances. If it's an experimental setting probably you should use the script as is. For production either convert to C++ or take a look at Cython or Swig.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python program to C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650243/608639)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you edit your Python script to make it return the rectangle's 4 points instead of drawing the rectangle around the detected object. Then use the way described in the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value) question to get the 4 points of the rectangle from the Python script and draw them in C++. Hope this helps!