# Multiple calls to Python interpreter embedded in C++ application yield segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, embed

This question has been posted earlier as an issue at [rigetti/pyquil](https://github.com/rigetti/pyquil/issues/835), where it has been recommended to ask Python experts before considering it a bug in Rigetti's pyquil library:

Consider the following mini application that creates a string containing QASM code in the host application and invokes the Python interpreter:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <sstream>

static void run()
{
  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << "import pyquil\n"
     << "qasm = 'H 0'\n"
     << "p = pyquil.Program(qasm)\n"
     << "qc = pyquil.get_qc('9q-square-qvm')\n"
     << "result = qc.run_and_measure(p, trials=1024)\n"
     << "print(result)\n";

  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString(ss.str().c_str());
  Py_Finalize();
}

int main()
{
  run();
  run();
  return 0;
}
```

*Remark:* In my real program am not using `PyRun_SimpleString` but, instead, the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value) to extract the return value. The problem is the same, so the above program is just meant as illustrating example to keep things as simple as possible.

Compiling the code under macOS 10.13.6 as follows

```sh
g++ -I/usr/local//homebrew/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -L/usr/local//homebrew/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib -lpython3.7m demo.cxx -o demo.exe
```

yields the following error:

```sh
{0: array([1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0]), 1: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 2: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 3: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 4: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 5: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 6: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 7: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), 8: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])}
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Removing the second `run()` from the `main()` function, i.e. no second invocation of the Python interpreter, solves the problem.

The segmentation fault occurs already at the `import pyquil` line. That is, already this code produces a segmentation fault in the second call to `run()`:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <sstream>

static void run()
{
  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << "import pyquil\n";

  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString(ss.str().c_str());
  Py_Finalize();
}

int main()
{
  run();
  run();
  return 0;
}
```

I have been using multiple invocations of the Python interpreter from the same host application with many other Python modules and never encountered this problem. Any help is appreciated.