# passing info from python to c prog

Tags: python, c

I created a C program and choose to use python as my GUI creator
I wrote the python GUI and decided to create a struct

```
typedef struct GUIcommunicator
{
    char action[MAX_SIZE];
    char params[MAX_PARAMS][MAX_SIZE];
}GUIcommunicator;
```

I using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value) I will return the 
struct from the python receive him in my C code

but I don't know how.
And I'd like to some help

(the function that sends the struct (the python code) already got the action and the params as string list )

Comment: It sounds like you need to call C from Python, not the other way around.

Comment: I know but I need to retrun answers to the c program

Comment: @EyalElbaz: Is it *returning* answers if they’re arguments to a call you’re making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing a linux based application, you can perform [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) using [FIFO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) files

For windows based applications, you could use [Named-pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipes)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the direction of the call, you end up with a `PyObject*` in C that refers to a `list` of strings.  Fetch [each element](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_GetItem), then fetch the string data pointer and size for a Python 2 [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/string.html#c.PyString_AsStringAndSize) or (the UTF-8 encoding of) a Python 3 [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize).  Check the size against `MAX_SIZE` (probably `MAX_SIZE-1`) and beware of embedded null characters, which your struct presumably cannot represent.

There are of course ways of accepting any iterable, converting elements to strings, *etc.*, if you want that flexibility.