# python3 C extension module with cp1252 encoded string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-extensions, cp1252, extension-modules

I am writing a Python3 extension module for an existing C++ library which returns a string that appears to be in cp1252 encoding. The C++ function signature is

```c
int get_name(std::string& name);
```

where `name` is the output variable that contains a string with c_str() contents like 0xb04600, which is DegreeSymbol in cp1252 code page, followed by upper case `F`, completed by the NULL character.

In my python extension C++ code, I wrote

```c
std::string name;
int retval = get_value(name);
py_retval = Py_BuildValue((char *) "is#", retval, (name).c_str(), (name).size());
```

However, this causes the following runtime exception

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

What is the correct way for me to return a cp2152 encoded string into python?

**UPDATE**
I figured out that if I use `y#` instead of `s#` to return a Python bytes object from the extension, then I can convert that bytes object back to a string in my python code with `.decode('cp1252')`. However, this is an extra step in Python that should be automated in the extension module. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how

Comment: I don't know enough about the Python C API to give you the code, but can't you build a `bytes` like you said and then call `.decode` *from C*, through the Python API, to get your final Python retvalue?

Comment: @Linuxios - that's exactly what I want to do (see my Update), but I cannot figure out the Python Extension Module C syntax for doing that.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3310608/1008938 and https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/

Comment: Maybe write simple python wrapper around this module which only will be changing encoding?

Answer (score 2):

[`PyUnicode_Decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_Decode) can do this job for any [standard encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) without even having to make a `bytes` object first.  (You can pass it with code `N` to `Py_BuildValue` to avoid worrying with reference counts, although that trick doesn’t apply in all cases.)