# Can I call cuda code written in cupy code from c++?

Tags: python, c++, cupy

If I have a simple sampling 3D points of the form

```
s = [[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2],[x3, y3, z3],[x4, y4, z4],.....]
```

in to voxels function implemented in cupy, Can I call that function from c++ code? We have c++ code calling tensorflow graph and execute in the car. Can I compile my cupy code into c++ binary and call that from c++ code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with CuPy but have a look at the Python C API (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/).
This allows you to run Python functions in C and C++.

Heres an example, running a function called *functionname* within *pythonfile.py* (Have not tested this but should be fine).

```
PyObject* pyModuleStr = PyString_FromString((char*)"pythonfile");
PyObject* pyModule = PyImport_Import(pyModuleStr);
PyObject* pyFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pyModule,(char*)"functionname");
PyObject_CallObject(pyFunction);
```

It is also possible to extract the function's return value, and add arguments.

Hope this helps!

*8)*

***EDIT***:
Heres a StackOverflow post which may be helpful ([Calling a python method from C/C++, and extracting its return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value)).