# Include Python.h in linux (ubuntu) using code::blocks

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x

I would like call python functions from C++. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have python 3.8 installed. The path where `Python.h` is located is `/usr/include/python3.8/Python.h`, which I found using the command line `sudo find / -iname python.h` in the terminal. In order to get started I tried to run the easiest code in code::blocks:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"starting interpreter."<<endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("Hallo from Python");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error message:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory|
```

My question is: Which libraries do I have to include and how do I include these in code::blocks?  For a detailed description I would be very thankful.

Greetings,
Ben

Comment: there's the recommended way: compile c code for python with python itself (using distutils) or you probably can just change your include  to something like `#include <python3/Python.h>` since `Python.h` isnt directly in your include paths if you havent done anything to them

Comment: I have tried to include ```#include <python3.8/Python.h>```. However, I get the following error message: ```fatal error: cpython/initconfig.h: No such file or directory```. How can I proceed ?

Comment: this is already discussed at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value