# Importing python file to c++ program - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, python-embedding

Following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286448/calling-a-python-method-from-c-c-and-extracting-its-return-value)

Assume I have the following files in the directory prog:

***main.cpp (located in the directory prog)***

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


Py_Initialize();

//Adding current path
PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
PyObject* path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
PyObject* cur_dir = PyUnicode_FromString("");
PyList_Append(path, cur_dir);

PyObject* myModuleString = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault((char*)"multiset_bell_numbers.py");
PyObject *pModule =  PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
if (pModule == nullptr) {
    PyErr_Print();
    throw std::runtime_error("pModule is empty");
}

return 0;
}
```

***multiset_bell_numbers.py (located in the directory prog)***

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_partitions



def calc_partitions(arr):
    res = list(multiset_partitions(arr))
    res.sort(key=lambda part:len(part))
    return res
```

***CMakeLists.txt***

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(prog)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
include_directories(${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(prog main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prog ${Python_LIBRARIES})
```

But still got an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiset_bell_numbers'

I have also tried to remove ".py" from the suffix of the string
What should I do?

Comment: Remember that `import` looks in the current working directory.  It's not the directory where the executable is.  If you have done `cd prog` and `main`, then it will work.

Comment: I made the executable in the same directory, but it's still doesn't work

Comment: What about if you pass just the module name without  the *.py* extension? Also the *C* source file location is irrelevant.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the executable is.  What matters is the WORKING DIRECTORY.  That's what Python searches.